# Ubuntu - upgrading docker-compose version

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, pip

new to Docker so this may be basic, but after my googling I have still not found a solution

I have a docker-compose.yml file I am trying to run (version for the file is "3.4", but I am getting the error:

```
"The compose file is invalid because:
     networks.default value Additional properties are not allowed ('name' was unexpected)
```

This is the portion of the docker-compose file that is failing:

```
networks:
    default:
        driver: bridge
        name: nssams_bridge
```

When I run (I am on Ubuntu 20.04)

```
docker-compose --version
```

It says the version is 1.25.0, I am not sure if that is a high enough version to support 3.4, is my guess.

But I have tried to update docker-compose many ways and none of them seem to work.

I have tried:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

and

```
sudo apt upgrade docker-compose
```

as well as

```
sudo pip install docker-compose
```

but after all of these, the docker-compose --version command still returns 1.25.0, build unknown

So how do I upgrade the docker-compose version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`name:` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#name-1) was added in Compose file format 3.5, so your 3.4 is one step too old.  I'd use 3.8 or 3.9 unless you have a specific reason to use something older:

```yaml
version: '3.8' # networks: { name: } requires a minimum of 3.5
networks:
    default:
        driver: bridge
        name: nssams_bridge
```

For many practical uses you can also just let Compose choose the name of the network, since you'll rarely interact with it directly.  Should you need manual `docker network` commands or to refer to the network from another Compose file, Compose will name the network `projectname_default`, using the current directory's name as the project name.  If that's acceptable for you then you can delete this `networks:` block entirely.

Comment: That was easy, thank you - not sure how I didn't find that information from my googling